# i386 support on amd64

Tags: dependencies, 64-bit, 32-bit

I'm running amd64 architecture, and some programs ask me for i386 architecture.

So I've used the `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` command, but nothing works to upgrade the whole Ubuntu.

Every single ****ing CLI thing I try says me "unmet dependencies required someway that we're unable to perform" and that's a thing that blocks me in absolutely EVERYTHING.

Comment: If you installed x86 (or 32bit which debian & ubuntu refer to as i386) you must re-install to switch to x86_64 (or 64bit).  You can add 32bit as an additional architecture to x86_64, but the reverse is not possible.  If you have error messages, you should provide them in full for us to help you the most.

Comment: Please include *exact* commands you're running and the *full error messages*.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, solved using the following:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude install winehq-stable
```

(After adding the correct winehq PPA.)

This removed wine-stable and installed both `wine-stable-i386`, `wine-stable:amd64`, and `winehq-stable`.

Thanks for reading, hope this case would be helpful.

Comment: How can it be, you didn't mention you were trying to install any specific program only "*some programs*".  It doesn't actually answer the question as you wrote it.